# How to mock claims in C#?

Tags: c#, api, claims

I am currently working on an API that uses `System.Security.ClaimsPrincipal`.

My API method code is as simple as below:

```
 var identityClaims = User.Claims; // User is part of System.security.claimsPrincipal
 var firstname = identityClaims .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "firstname").Value;
 var lastname = identityClaims .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "lastname").Value;
```

I want to create a unit test where I can mock value of `FirstName` and `LastName`.

I have seen the example below online, but it only seem to be setting 1 claim value - John Doe, while I need to set up `FirstName` and `LastName`.

```
var claims = new List<Claim>() 
{ 
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "username"),
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "userId"),
    new Claim("name", "John Doe"),
};
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "TestAuthType");
var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
```

How can I mock the firstname and lastname based on above example?

The `ClaimTypes.xxxx` does not give me any option for FirstName, LastName.

Answer (score 3):

You can set claim types `GivenName` and `Surname` for that.

```cs
new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email), // Email
// Dotnet uses this as username but its used differently. Facebook uses this as full name.
new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.FullName), // Full Name
new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName), // First Name
new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName), // Last Name
new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserUniqueIdentifier.ToString()) // User Id or User Name
```